# firebase firebase snapshot as a custom model

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, casting

Im trying to retrieve data from firebase snapshot as my custom data model called "RadioModel"

```
class RadioModel {
    var title : String?
    var image: String?
    var link: String?
    var description: String?

    init(title: String, image: String, link: String, description: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.image = image
        self.link = link
        self.description = description
    }
}
```

[image: firebase data]

what i'm trying to do is below, but menu gives me a nil value

```
mydb = Database.database().reference().child("radioStaions")
    mydb?.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        //print(snapshot)
        let menu = snapshot.value as! RadioModel
        self.radioMenu.append(menu)
    })
```

any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you're missing a loop over `snapshot.children`. Right now you're observing `radioStaions`, and that gives you a snapshot that contains multiple radio stations. To get to each individual radio station, you'll need to loop over `snapshot.children` like:

```
mydb?.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
   for station in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
      print(station.key)
      let desc = station.childSnapshot(forPath: "description").value as! String
      print(desc)
   }        
})
```

There might be other problems with your code, but this is definitely one that breaks it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Jay. I always forget which class on iOS has the `child` method, and which one needs a longer name. :-/